# Local Service fails in ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, c#, arcgis-web-adf

I have a web ADF application which connects to a map service (either via WMS or Internet Service using http). I'd like to use DCOM connections (faster as the documentation states), so I would like to use a 'Local Service' for the map service..

but only WMS or Internet Service types work, when I choose the Local Service type the map disappears and my app is no longer able to retrieve the map

Has anyone ever experienced such an issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you are correct at 10.1 the service model is changing, but for 10.0/sp1/sp2 you should still be able to connect to your services.
 I would first look to your user permissions/settings for the user connecting to the service to make sure its a agsusers group so that it can access that service. This was very specific in the ADF generation to ensure that said application had permissions on the machine to access the service layer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm curious where in the documentation you've seen it stated that Local connections are faster than Internet connections?

Beyond that, you're almost certainly experiencing permissions problems as D.E. Wright mentions. If you're using the default setup under IIS then depending on your version of Windows your web app will probably be running under IUSR_ or the ASPNET user account. You can change this to a specific named user that you create (what I'd recommend). No matter what, you'll have to add the user account to the `agsusers` group.

Comment: I just heard it from someone, so http connections are equally fast too?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that ArcGIS from version 10.1 and forth will only support http connections, local connection will not be supported any longer.